# Understanding the Spectrum obtained after Fast Fourier Transform application or analyse data

Tags: python, fft, analytics, data-analysis, spectrum

I have obtained, data by performing some long task and then tried to obtain the Fast fourier transform of it using below code in python. I have attached two file named RK4_step_Gradient_EF_0.01_Harmonics_Data_0.out.npz and RK4_step_Gradient_EF_0.01_Harmonics_Data_1.out.npz on link given below, I used this to obtain the FFT by loading it in the python.

But, the spectrum obtained is different from one another. As in figure the blue graph corresponding to data"RK4_step_Gradient_EF_0.01_Harmonics_Data_0.out.npz" shows less harmonics, while orange graph with data - "RK4_step_Gradient_EF_0.01_Harmonics_Data_1.out.npz" shows many harmonics.

I want to understand or see how is the data in orange is different from blue. Why does orange curve shows many harmonics as compared to blue curve Or Which part of data in orange curve contributes to so many harmonics. As this is very important for me to analyse. I have tried a lot but cannot understand which data of orange produces so many harmonics. Hence I request if someone can help me to analyse the data or spectrum.

In one way I am trying to do reverse process like using spectrum and data, I am trying to see which part of data led to this many harmonics in orange curve as compared to blue curve.

I humbly request to please please help.

Thank you so much for reading my post.

[Harmonics with Blue and Orange curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9TED.png)

[Data Link](https://figshare.com/s/0156cd367a23882a0989)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.fftpack import fft, fftfreq, fftshift
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import zeros
import math
from matplotlib.ticker import ScalarFormatter
import plotly.tools as tls
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, iplot
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import matplotlib as mpl
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
sns.set(style="whitegrid")
import plotly.io as pio
pio.templates.default = "simple_white"

f_name = 'RK4_step_Gradient_EF_0.01_Harmonics_Data_0.out.npz'
    
dat_article     = np.load(f_name)


Acceleration_x     = dat_article['ax_listG']
Acceleration_y     = dat_article['ay_listG']

#Fast Fourier Transform

N = 200000
af_y = fft(Acceleration_y)
af_x = fft(Acceleration_x)

ayf = (af_x**2 + af_y**2)
ay = fftshift(ayf)

xf = fftfreq(N,0.001e-15)
xf_1 = fftshift(xf)/(37.5e13)

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(
go.Scatter(x=xf_1,y=(1.0/N * np.abs(ay))) )
fig.update_xaxes(range=[0, 50])

fig.update_layout(yaxis_type="log", title="Velocity & Position equal to 0,  Gradient = 0, -1/1e-9",
          xaxis_title="Harmonic order(ω/ω0)",
          yaxis_title="FFT of acceleration",
          font=dict(family="Arial",size=14,color="RebeccaPurple")) 


fig.update_layout(legend=dict(
                                orientation="h",
                                yanchor="bottom",
                                y=1.02,
                                xanchor="right",
                                x=1
                            ))
fig.update_layout(
    xaxis = dict(
        tickmode = 'linear',
        tick0 = 1,
        dtick = 1
    )
)
fig.write_html("Harmonic.html")
```